# Encrypting large data using azure key vault RSA key and C#

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I need to encrypt data in Azure Function using rsa-2048 key from Azure Key Vault.

The problem here is that data I need to encrypt is much larger than the maximum length that can be encrypted using asymmetric rsa key.

My question is if there is any method to encrypt larger data using only asymmetric rsa key from azure key vault or do I need to create symmetric key which would be encrypted using the asymmetric key?

If so I could really use some code example to demonstrate how this is done. I'm somewhat new to cryptography so I'm not that familiar with all this. I have managed to encrypt smaller amount of data using the rsa key I have in key vault.

Comment: How big is the data that you want to encrypt?

Comment: It can be maximum of 20MB text or xml file.

Comment: There's a pattern for this that Microsoft recommends, you use a CEK (content encryption key) encrypted with a KEK (key encryption key) which is essentially what you describe - using a symmetric key for encryption. The reference to this key is then stored in the blob metadata since you may use multiple keys for encryption. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/client-side-encryption?tabs=dotnet

Answer (score 1):

For example in a HTTPS connection, they use asymmetric (like RSA, ECDSA...) encryption using private/public keys to exchange the initial secrets, but then they use symmetric encryption (Like AES) for encrypting the actual data transfer.

So, I guess you're using the wrong encryption algorithm for the job.